# MariaSQL LIKE returns no results

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-like, mariasql

I have a query with `LIKE '%query%'` ,with `query` being the exact value that is in the table, that doesn't return a result. When I try the exact same query with `q` it does return results.

Is this normal?

Comment: I don't know this db, but no that is not normal and it usually relates to the data having an unprintable character like a Tab inside the string = so your query looks like the same thing as the data in the table  but it actually is not.

Comment: It works when I try `column_name  = query`

Comment: can you check the documentation then to make sure % is a wildcard? I knwo it is for SQl Server but it woudl nto be for every db.

Comment: It says it matches any number of characters, including zero

Comment: Perhaps you meant that 'it works when I try `column_name = "query"`' (with quotes)?

Comment: yes my bad! but `LIKE '%query%'` should give the same results as `="query"` when there is only one row with `query` being the value in the particular column